# jquery ajax form + ajax setTimeout don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, settimeout

I am working on my simple test page that was full of forms. As one of you posted few days ago I am now using jquery to use ajax and avoid to refresh the page once one of the submit button are pressed. So just following the template I've found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I've added to my webpage this piece of code:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

What I experience is that now the forms work perfectly but the ajax setTimeout function does not work anymore! If I remove the previous code the ajax setTimeout is working again. Have you guys a clue on why it does like that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myff(abc)
    {

        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis3').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self(abc);}, 1000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'loadfunc.php' + '?abc=' + abc);
            $http.send(null);
        }
    }

</script>
```

new code:

```
<script>   
        $(document).ready(function() {


        $('#s1hvform1').ajaxForm(function() {
        });

      sendreq(abc);
});

function sendreq(abc)
{
    $.get('loadfu.php?abc='+abc,function(r)
    {          
        $('#ReloadThis2').html(r);
        setTimeout(function(){sendreq(abc);},1000);        });
}           

</script>


<div id="ReloadThis2">Loading data...</div>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, when writing code that uses jQuery the convention is to use `$` at the start of a variable name to indicate that it contains a jQuery object. Given that neither `$http` or `$self` will do so, it's slightly misleading (though I guess not exactly incorrect) to name them the way you have done.

Comment: I think you want to use "bind": setTimeout(this.bind(this,abc),1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout() is not an ajax function, and it has to be passed a function handle in the form of a string I am fairly certain. Also, why are you not using jquery for this, seeing as you are in the first code block?

```
function sendRequest(abc)
{
    $.get('loadfunc.php?abc='+abc,function(r)
    {
        $('#ReloadThis3').html(r);
        setTimeout(function(){sendRequest(abc);},1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're wrong, `setTimeout()` can take a function reference. That function reference can either be the name of a defined function, or an anonymous function, depending on whether or not you need to pass arguments to it.

Comment: I never used jquery.. I am trying to make your sample code working but it does not.. moreover in your example could I pass a variable to sendRequest as sendRequest(abc)?

Comment: Well, we all learn something new every day, don't we? I will edit it to reflect.

Comment: I see.. but definitely I doing something wrong with it.. I've put that function in the <script> .. </script> where I have $(document).ready(function() { ......bindings of my forms..... sendRequest() }   and then function sendRequest(abc) .....          In the beginning it works but it seems not to refresh itself

Comment: You have everything you need to solve the problem yourself. You need to read my code more carefully. ;)

Comment: Ops sorry I wrongly copied/pasted one line, but I did put it correctly in my trial, in the console log I still don't see the call..

Comment: Sounds like your server might be cacheing the page or something.